# sfGuardAuth across multiple apps

Tags: symfony1, credentials, sfguard, members

I've got 3 apps: Backend, Frontend and Members.
And I've got 2 credentials: Administrators and Members.

Administrators are imported by default but Members are created in the Backend.
When a Member is created, an event handler also inserts this Member as a sf_guard_user and of course, the proper relations in sf_guard_user_group and sf_guard_user_permission.

That's the boring part, now the fun:

Frontend is **not** secured, but Members **is** and using these credentials: [administrator, member].

According to all this, Members created in the Backend that also get inserted (correctly as far as I can tell) **should** be able to login to the **Members secured app**, since they get the **member** group/permission/credential.

This is not happenning, the only ones that can login to the Members app are the administrators, which is not wrong, but either is the fact that correctly created Member users can't login to it.

The error thrown by the guard is the classic: The username and/or password is invalid.

*Now that I edit the error, the salt comes to mind: How would one emulate the inserting of the salt as the guard does it? Maybe that's what I'm not inserting correctly (or inserting at all) and thus the password invalid error (and in fact everythine else I've described is ok! omg)*

And that's my problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

[administrator, member] means both are required, I believe.

I think you want [[administrator, member]] for the credential requirement.

Also, yes, you will want to make sure you use a salt, and set the algo.

```
    parent::_set('password', call_user_func_array($algorithm, array($salt.$password)));
```

Salt before password, as well.

Comment: I wasn't correctly adding the salt, but that didn't solved the main issue ):